# How to get JSON from api in listview labels in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, binding, viewmodel

I have the following code that retrieves json from an api. This works because when I put a breakpoint on it, it neatly shows the json from the url.

**The json looks like this when I put a breakpoint on it**

[image]

**And the code of getting the json from the url looks like this**
public static List GetAllSpecTypes(string acces_Token, string domain, out bool result)
{
result = true;

```
        var specTypes = new List<Specification>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string url = $"{domain}/api/specification/GetSpecificationType";
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", acces_Token);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        specTypes = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Specification>>(json);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //log!
            }
        }
        return specTypes;
    }
```

**And the json from the breakpoint is this:**

```
"[{\"SpecificationTypeId\":1,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Overig\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":2,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Eten/Drinken\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":3,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Parkeren\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":4,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Ander vervoer\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":5,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Materiaal\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":6,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Persoonlijke uitgaven\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":7,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Uitgaven cliënt\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":8,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Overnachting\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":9,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Congres / beursbezoek\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":10,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Brandstof\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":11,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Auto kosten\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":12,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Eigen vervoer\"},{\"SpecificationTypeId\":14,\"SpecificationTypeName\":\"Vervoer\"}]"
```

This method should return the specTypes to a viewmodel. But when I do, it's empty when I put a breakpoint on it.

[image]

**That code is as follows**

```
        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.Source = new List<SourceItem>();

            var data = Api.GetAllSpecTypes(Settings.AccessToken, Settings.Domain, out var valid);

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Source.Add(new SourceItem(item.SpecificationName, item.SpecificationId));
            }
        }
```

What I want to achieve is that here that json is returned from the api call so that I can bind it to a label in a listview.

The listview xaml looks like this in which I put in the label where I use the following:

```
                                      <Label
                                            FontSize="18"
                                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                                            TextColor="#474747"
                                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

What should be in the label are the specificationnames coming from the json

How can i achieve this?

This is my entire viewmodel according to my question

public class SourceItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public SourceItem(string name, int id)
{
this.Name = name;
this.Id = id;
}

```
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private int id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return this.id; }
            set
            {
                this.id = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        private bool isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return this.isSelected; }
            set
            {
                this.isSelected = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }

    }


    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isSelected = false;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => _isSelected;
            set
            {
                if (_isSelected != value)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.Source = new List<SourceItem>();

            var data = Api.GetAllSpecTypes(Settings.AccessToken, Settings.Domain, out var valid);

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Source.Add(new SourceItem(item.SpecificationName, item.SpecificationId));
            }
        }

        public List<SourceItem> Source { get; set; }
    }
```

**And the Specification Class for the JSON is the following:**

```
  public class Specification
    {
        public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
        public string SpecificationName { get; set; }
        public string SpecificationDescription { get; set; }

    }
```

How do I get the specification names from the json in the xaml label based on my question?

thanks in advance

Comment: have you verified that your json is getting deserialized properly?  That's the FIRST thing you need to do.  Debugging all of your other code is pointless if this step isn't working.

Comment: json "Specification**Type**Id", C# "SpecificationId".  The names either need to match exactly, or you need to provide a mapping attribute

Comment: What can i do to match them? @Jason

Answer (score 1):

your json looks like

```
"[{\"SpecificationTypeId\":1,\"SpecificationTypeName\"
```

while your C# classes do not include the "Type" in the name

```
public class Specification
{
    public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
    public string SpecificationName { get; set; }
    public string SpecificationDescription { get; set; }
}
```

you either need to rename your C# properties to match the json, or use an attribute to map the name

```
[JsonProperty("SpecificationTypeId")]
public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
```